# Dynamic Default Day Parameter

Tags: tableau-api

Good day,

I would like to create parameters with the following conditions:

- Start Date Range between 03/01/2019-03/31/2019 (done)
- End day range 03/01/2019-03/31/2019
- Default end day is set to the day of today but in March (so if I open the wbook tomorrow it will be 03/22/2019

It's a bit complexe and your help is much appreciated.

Comment: I am unable to get you. Can you please elaborate a bit more? How many parameters do you want to create? What is the output calculation desired? Do you mean last day in March equal to today's day?

Comment: @AnilGoyal I want a date range filter using 2 parameters: start date and end date. The end date is by default set to the day of the month with the same number as the day the workbook is opened. If I open the workbook on 22nd of January 2034, the default end date filter will be 22nd of March 2019.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Please tell me one more thing, do this default end date is the final value you want to enter into filter or you just want the user to chose any date from March but want to just show day as default value?  I'm not sure about your usage of this default.  tableau doesn't allow dynamic default values for parameters.  But final value can be managed

Answer (score 0):

1- Create calc field that takes day of today and month/year
DATEPARSE("dd, MM, yyyy", str(Today()) + ", " + str(03) + str(2019))
2- In End date parameter > when opening workbook > select calculated date